Which Palestinian government is getting recognized?
Norway, Spain and Ireland have moved to formally recognize Palestine as a state. There was a discussion about what Spain specifically was recognizing, but the answers focused heavily on the land aspect. I am assuming that the current Gaza + West Bank borders are where any Palestinian state would reside.
The catch here is you effectively have had two governments since 2005.

The West bank is still run by Fatah (formerly the PLO)
Gaza has been run by Hamas (who have openly executed the members of Fatah in Gaza)

Fatah has been steadily losing ground to Hamas (Dec 2023)

In a two-way presidential race, Ismail Haniyeh, the exiled political leader of Hamas, would trounce Abbas

A lot of that is due to the fact that 2005 was the last election and Abbas is trying to hold on to the power he currently has (he has repeatedly delayed elections, which likely contributes to his unpopularity).
Have Norway, Spain, Ireland, or any other government that wants to formally recognize a Palestinian state indicated which of these two groups they see as the leadership of said state? Do they see both as equally legitimate?

Per Reuters, "The three countries recognised a Palestinian state with its borders to be demarcated as they were prior to 1967, with Jerusalem as the capital of both Israel and Palestine. However, they also recognised that those borders may change in any eventual talks to reach a final settlement."

If you look at the quotes in the related Q (that you've linked), the 3 EU countries are not recognizing Hamas', obviously.

@KelvinSherlock That's true, but the problem is they're recognizing Palestine without negotiations first. Israel isn't going to redraw borders just because a handful of countries want it. At least for now, countries recognizing Palestine would have to take the current borders as-is. I think the question about where the borders would be has been pretty well discussed in other posts, tho.

Are you only interested in Norway, Spain and Ireland or also in what government the other 140 countries that recognize Palestina recognize?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution "Norway, Spain, Ireland, or any other government that wants to recognize a Palestinian state" I don't know of any others formally doing so, but any that have moved to formally do so will be acceptable

There are over 140 countries that have moved in the past to formally recognize Palestina. Norway, Spain and Ireland are hardly the first ones there. Just want to make sure that answering for these 140 countries would answer the question or not.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I edited to make it clear there has to be formal recognition. A lot of countries have expressed interest in recognition, but have not followed up with anything formal.

Recognition of a state is not the same as recognition of the government. Recognition of the government is not the same as approving that government. US recognizes Russia, Iran, China and North Korea as states, but diplomatic relations with all four are quite strained.

Even if one sees this Q as pushing the "are we rewarding Hamas by recognition?" line, answers can still point out the nuances between recognizing a country and recognizing a particular government as the legitimate government of that country.  Reopen.

Voting to reopen. This close reason does not appear accurate: "The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center." I cannot see in the question any sign of promoting or discrediting any entity. It's a question about which of the two governments is being recognized when the state is being recognized. Neither of the two governments is being promoted or discredited.

Palestinian liberation organization (PLO) is recognized as the sole legitimate representative of the Palestinian people, and represents them in the UN (with an observer status):

The Palestine Liberation Organization is recognized by the Arab League as "the sole and legitimate representative of the Palestinian people",[14][41] and by the United Nations as "the representative of the Palestinian people".[68]

The Palestinian Authority that handles everyday government responsibilities is technically distinct from the PLO:

The administrative responsibilities accorded to the PA were limited to civil matters and internal security and did not include external security or foreign affairs.[26] Palestinians in the diaspora and inside Israel were not eligible to vote in elections for the offices of the Palestinian Authority.[27] The PA was legally separate from the Palestine Liberation Organization (PLO), which continues to enjoy international recognition as the sole legitimate representative of the Palestinian people, representing them at the United Nations under the name "Palestine".[28][29]

Hamas also accepted PLO as the sole representative of the Palestinian people as a pre-condition for its participation in Palestinian elections :

On 28 June 2006, Hamas signed the second version of (originally) 'the Palestinians' Prisoners Document' which supports the quest for a Palestinian state "on all territories occupied in 1967".[68][329][330] This document also recognized the PLO as "the sole legitimate representative of the Palestinian people", and states that "the negotiations" should be conducted by PLO and President of the Palestinian National Authority and eventual agreements must be ratified by either the Palestinian National Council or a general referendum "held in the homeland and the Diaspora".

However, Hamas is not a member of PLO and is currently in a state of open rebellion against it.
PLO vs. PA

The 1993–1995 Oslo Accords deliberately detached the Palestinian population in the Occupied Palestinian Territories from the PLO and the Palestinians in exile by creating a Palestinian Authority (PA) for the Territories. A separate parliament and government were established. Mahmoud Abbas was one of the architects of the Oslo Accords.[54][55]
Although many in the PLO opposed the Oslo Agreements, the executive committee and the Central Council approved the Accords. It marked the beginning of the PLO's decline, as the PA came to replace the PLO as the prime Palestinian political institution. Political factions within the PLO that had opposed the Oslo process were marginalized.
The PLO managed to overcome the separation by uniting the power in PLO and PA in one individual, Yasser Arafat. In 2002, Arafat held the functions of Chairman of the PLO/Executive Committee; Chairman of Fatah, the dominating faction within the PLO; as well as President of the Palestinian National Authority. He also controlled the Palestinian National Security Forces.[56]
Only during the Hamas-led PA Government in 2006–2007 did the PLO resurface. After Hamas took over Gaza in 2007, Abbas issued a decree suspending the PLC and some sections of the Palestinian Basic Law, and appointed Salam Fayyad as prime minister.
The PLO remains the official representative of the State of Palestine at the UN.

Remark
In response to comments (This doesn't not answer explicitly the question.) it is necessary to note that de jure recognition means recognizing that the state fullfils all the necessary requirements under the International law:

A distinction is also drawn between de jure and de facto recognition. If a state is accorded de
jure recognition, that means all the preconditions under international law for final and
complete recognition have been fulfilled. De facto recognition has a comparatively less
binding effect, because the legal relationship – though effectively in existence – is only
provisional. Provisional de facto recognition for political reasons can of course be converted
to de jure recognition once all the required legal preconditions have been fulfilled.

In other words, only the PLO, representing Palestinians in the United nations can be meaningfully recognized as Palestinian State.
This recognition does not mean that the countries are obliged to establish diplomatic relationships with the Palestinian government, i.e., recognize this government - in this sense the title of the question (Which Palestinian government is getting recognized?) might cause some confusion. As per Wikipedia:

Diplomatic recognition must be distinguished from formal recognition of states or their governments.2 The fact that states do not maintain bilateral diplomatic relations does not mean that they do not recognize or treat one another as states. A state is not required to accord formal bilateral recognition to any other state, and some have a general policy of not doing so, considering that a vote for its membership of an international organisation restricted to states, such as the United Nations, is an act of recognition.


"Sole legitimate representative etc." - ignoring the philosophical question of what representation means exactly, recognizing a Palestinian state necessarily means declaring that this phrase is no longer valid, and in fact, that the PLO loses representative status completely, in favor of the State of Palestine. There is no such thing as recognizing a sovereign state while, supposedly, a non-state organization is the sole representative of its people.

@einpoklum it is not up to Spanish or anyone else to decide how Palestinians call their state, and countries are known to change their names. The point is that most "Palestinian supporters" outside of ME don't understand the difference between Hamas and PLO - which is rather telling about what they actually support.

I don't see how your comment relates to mine. Suppose, say, Puerto Rico seems a movement for liberation from the US, and that the UN recognizes the "Puertorican Liberation Organization" as the sole representative of the Puerto-Ricans. When this movement succeeds, and the independent state of Puerto Rico is established, it would be recognized as the "sole representative of the Puerto-Ricans", by admission into the UN as a member with the recognized territory of the island of Puerto-Rico. Wouldn't it?

@einpoklum Puerto Ricans will decide for themselves how they name their representative in the UN - they may choose a new name or keep the old one, even if it looks semantically outdated. In either case, it will be the same entity. I am not sure recognition means recognizing specific borders - Palestine is clearly problematic in this sense.

Everything I've seen suggests that they will recognise the PA, whose head is currently from Fatah.
This quote from the Norwegian government make it clear in that case:

"Norway will continue to support the Palestinian state-building project. We must strengthen the Palestinian Authority under the leadership of Prime Minister Muhammed Mustafa, and we must work for the Palestinian Authority to govern in Gaza following a ceasefire and for there to be one Palestinian government. The goal is to achieve a Palestinian state that is politically cohesive, and that derives from the Palestinian Authority,’ said Mr Eide."

https://www.regjeringen.no/en/aktuelt/norway-recognises-palestine-as-a-state/id3040194/
Its unclear what would happen should circumstances ever conspire to make someone from Hamas head of the PA.
It is also worth noting that while other international organisation recognise the PLO as the sole legitimate representative of the Palestinians, that us not what the Norwegian minister said.

This does seem to answer the question! ;)

@user13964273: Do these three states hold the position that Putin is not the head-of-state of the Russian Federation?

@user13964273: Recognition of who is the head of a state is not something another state can do. That is, it can try, e.g. the US decision that Huan Guaido is somehow the president of Venezuela; and there are cases of civil war where two factions vie for external recognition - but that's not where we're at. Also, I'm no specialist on EU institutions, but Parliament resolutions aren't binding, as opposed to laws passed; or am I wrong?

There is no catch because state recognition is orthogonal to
recognition of governments:

The recognition of a state under international law is a declaration
of intent by one state to acknowledge another power as a "state"
within the meaning of international law. Recognition constitutes a
unilateral declaration of intent. It is entirely at the discretion
of any state to decide to recognize another as a subject of
international law. [...] When a state recognizes a government, it
acknowledges a group of persons as competent to act as an organ of
the state in question and to represent it in terms of international
law.

The very famous British international lawyer Hersch Lauterpacht wrote about it in 1944:

To recognize a community as a State is to declare that it fulfills
the conditions of statehood as required by international law. If
these conditions are present, existing States are under the duty to
grant recognition.

The Montevideo Convention is sometimes appealed to when it comes
to deciding whether an entity fullfills the conditions Lauterpacht
refers to. However, recongition is at the state's own discretion so
saying that these states' recognition of Palestine is wrong because of
whatever is a moot point.

I think this is correct. You could recognize the state of Palestine and then possibly not recognize either Hamas or the PLO, or just recognize the PLO. Or possibly both of them, although that might not be a sound decision legally or policy-wise.

The Montevideo Convention you link indicates that possessing a government is one of the criteria for being a State. It seems somewhat odd to state "We recognize you as a state, which means recognizing you have a government, but we don't recognize your government." There's also "capacity to enter into relations with the other states", which begs the question of who is doing the relating, if not the government.

... Or maybe the issue here is multiple slightly different definitions of "government". e.g. the mechanistic/political system versus the specific people running the place. (That is, for someone in the UK, "form a new government" refers to any time the Prime Minister changes. But for someone from the US, "form a new government" would refer to 1789 and the signing of the Constitution, and would be a complete misnomer in a post-election context.)

Maybe my answer wasn't clear because you misunderstood it. The Montevideo convention provides guidelines but it's ultimately up to the state itself to decide whether to extend recognition. There are no "gotchas" here. States make the rules and the rules now say what Norway, Spain, and Ireland recognize Palestine. Arguing whether they were wrong or not is pointless because they did and here we are.

@R.M.: One way to potentially thread the line of "We recognize you as a state, which means recognizing you have a government, but we don't recognize your government." is to realize the last step makes a distinction between legitimate governments and illegitimate governments. You don't have to claim their government won a fair and free election, or has standing to be the legitimate leader of the country, to agree that the debate about the leader is a debate about a leader of a country.

Norway, Spain, Ireland and other governments that formally recognized a Palestinian state have not clearly indicated which of the two groups, Fatah or Hamas, they see as the leadership of the Palestinian state.
It is likely that a future change of Palestinian leadership from Fatah to Hamas (recognized as a terrorist group by many Western states) will preserve the status of recognition of the Palestinian state by the above countries.
This prediction is based on historical evidence. After all, most countries continued to recognize Iran, Syria, South Sudan, Myanmar and other states as "states" long after their governments changed and became closely associated with terrorist groups or committed numerous war crimes or crimes against humanity.
References and commentaries:

The Irish premier said the recognition comes from a belief in “freedom and justice,” and that peace can only be secured by “the free will of a free people.”
...
Speaking to Spain’s lower house, Sanchez said that Spain’s recognition is a decision “for peace, for justice and for coherence.”

Norway, Ireland, Spain move to recognize Palestinian state, drawing Israeli fury | The Times of Israel
These statements can be reasonably interpreted that if Palestinians elect Hamas into government, as they had done so in Gaza a while ago, Ireland and Spain will continue to recognize the Palestinian state ruled by Hamas. After all, such would have been then "the free will of a free people" and "justice".


"State Sponsors of Terrorism" is a designation applied to countries that are alleged to have "repeatedly provided support for acts of international terrorism" per the United States Department of State.
...
In 1979, the first such list was published by the State Department, designating Iraq, Libya, South Yemen, and Syria as terrorist states.[3] As of 2024, the list consists of Cuba, Iran, North Korea, and Syria.[4] The countries that were once on the list but have since been removed are: Iraq, Libya, South Yemen (dissolved in 1990), and Sudan. A resolution concerning the addition of Russia to the list was introduced to the senate following Russian invasion of Ukraine in 2022.

State Sponsors of Terrorism (U.S. list) - Wikipedia


The United States called out genocide and atrocities happening in six countries — Myanmar (also known as Burma,) China, Ethiopia, Iraq, Syria and South Sudan — as part of a report highlighting how the U.S. government is using financial, diplomatic and other measures to try to stop them.
Secretary of State Antony Blinken on Monday released an annual report on genocide and atrocities prevention.
"This year, for the first time, the report provides direct detailed accounts of atrocities taking place in specific countries, including Burma, Ethiopia, China and Syria. These places represent some of the toughest foreign policy challenges on our agenda," Blinken said.

US Calls Out Genocide, Atrocities Committed in 6 Countries

See also the list here: Foreign Terrorist Organizations - United States Department of State

The countries found on the above lists, sometimes on more than one list, were continued to be recognized as "states". They are rarely "unrecognized". Similarly, if the leadership of the future Palestinian state changes from Fatah to Hamas, it will most probably continue to be recognized as a state, Hamas' terrorist acts, such as the one on October 7, 2023, notwithstanding.

They have declared their decision as an urgent decision not to lose the two-state solution in order not to lose the peace opportunity altogether, so I guess this is not deeply studied by them, not concluded upon, and this also explains why so late they are declaring such a recognition, after so many countries before them.
Indeed one may assume their natural choice will be PLO, as some other answers have already pointed above, but this is not what they can count on so strongly, as PLO is weakly supported by Palestinian people, at least compared to Hamas. So I guess they have recognized Palestine as a state without really pointing to a specific government currently in power, that would be a future concern left for future; and again I guess they will try their best to affect the future governments in Palestine so they will still be able to recognize Palestine as a state.
What now they did is only to affect NOW on the war currently happening, before Israel reaches a point with no acceptable future in the region, accepting the two-state solution as more appealing than nothing when Israel is condemned by all countries including its CURRENT allies.
I look at this recognition as one last try to save Israel, so it is why they need not to determine which group they will support in future Palestine for now. This is an act of war to help Israel, but Israel doesn't like to accept this way these countries try to support it, so all the complains in the media you hear ...

I'm having difficulty understanding how recognising Palestine is supposed to be an attempt to help Israel rather than Palestine, or what you mean by it being "one last try to save Israel". Save it from what, exactly?

@F1Krazy, that it is a help to Israel doesn't mean it is not a hep to Palestine. A good solution is a solution that serves for several goals all at once. But why did they decide such at this section of the history? Were Palestinians not suffering before? Why they are recognizing Palestine as a state this much late? Why did each of them do what they did in cooperation with two other countries and not individually? ... Maybe because they wished to be least blamed/criticized this way by US, other Westerners, and Israel;

and maybe because they wanted to manage their own people as they are right now so angry; and maybe because they think Israel, crossing the red lines one after another, can no longer be supported as the one-state solution any further, so a two-state solution will be better if it could stop Israel from going farther into world-wide condemnation, assuming two-state solution being better than no-Israel solution anyway.

Hamas opposes the two-state solution and rejects the agreements concluded in the name of the Palestinian people by their officially recognized representatives, such as PLO and PA.
